# Bad practice to just use UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute?

Tags: c#, silverlight, uri

Is there any downside to ALWAYS using UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute (C# / Silverlight), aside from some minor loss of performance, instead of checking if the path is relative or not and using the correct UriKind?

```
Uri nav = new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Stated otherwise: Using the above code, is there ever a time when it will be evaluated as a relative path when it should have been evaluated as an absolute path? Is one checked before the other? Is it possible a pathcould satisfactorily be a relative path && an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

I found a really interesting Video and some descriptions below

Yo can Go through

[uri Kind Desc](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-18-Navigating-Between-Pages)

This text is a part of the description. Please go through it I hope it will clear your concept.

**But what about the UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute? That's a bit trickier. The best I can figure out is that we're simply asking the runtime to figure it out for itself. It will attempt to clean up the UriString we provide and figure out where resources are.**